# 25 movie clips. 1 function for all

Tags: function, movieclip, var

Hi I have 25 instances of the same movie clip and I want to be able to give the same function to all movie clips without having to write it 25 times.
I know I would use something like myMovie(i) and get i from 1 - 25 but dont know how.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what language are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to learn about *arrays*... but your question is vague and I'm not sure if that's what you really mean.

Comment: as3. i dont think i want an array maybe a switch function. Il try that